# converting specific part of string to integer

Tags: c, string, struct, strcpy, atoi

***updated with how i stored the string into my struct**

I have a struct as below:

```
struct patient {
    char name[30], ID[8];
    int age, phoneNo;
};
```

and i've written the following code:

```
int searchName()
{
    char search[30];
    char record[60];
    const char s[2] = ",";
    struct patient c;
    char a[8];
    int IDno;

FILE* fPtr;
    fPtr = fopen("patient.txt", "r");

    printf("Enter name to search : ");
    getchar();
    fgets(search, 30, stdin);

    //remove the '\n' at the end of string
    search[strcspn(search, "\n")] = 0;

    while (fgets(record, 60, fPtr))
    {
        // strstr returns start address of substring in case if present
        if (strstr(record, search))
        {
            char* pStr = strtok(record, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                strcpy(c.ID, pStr);
            }
            pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                strcpy(c.name, pStr);
            }
            pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                c.age = atoi(pStr);
            }
            pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                c.phoneNo = atoi(pStr);
            }
        }

    }

    printf("%s", c.ID);
    strcpy(a, c.ID);
    printf("\n%s", a);
    IDno = atoi(a);
    printf("\n%d", IDno);
    return 0;
}
```

the code allows me to search for a string in a file, separate the string into smaller strings using `strtok`, then store them into the struct. suppose i stored a string "PT3" into `c.ID` in the struct. in my program, I am trying to copy the string of "PT3" from `c.ID` to `a`, then convert `a` to an integer `IDno` using `atoi`. I'm not too sure about this, but I think by using `atoi` to convert "PT3" to an integer, only the integer "3" will remain in `IDno`, which is exactly when I want.

**edit: the problem appears to be that i am unable to convert "PT3" to an integer using `atoi`. would appreciate help on getting the number "3" from "PT3" to be stored into `IDno`.**

Comment: post a [mre], the current snippet is wrong for more than one reason.

Comment: @SouravGhosh hi, i've updated the code with how i stored the string into my struct. hope it helps.

Comment: `But currently the string stored in c.ID isn't being copied into a` Why do you think that? Could you post the output of your program?

Comment: `but I think by using atoi to convert "PT3" to an integer, only the integer "3" will remain in IDno` it does not work that way. It will continue conversion from beginning till it finds a non-numerical character in the entry. In this case, there's none.

Comment: @KamilCuk hi, it appears that i overlooked and it's working. sorry for the trouble. now the problem is i can't convert `a` to an integer `IDno`. would appreciate help on that.

Comment: @SouravGhosh thank you for pointing out the problem in my code. is there any way i could store the "3" from "PT3" into `IDno`?

Comment: There are many ways, but for that we need to know what the input pattern is. Is it always two chars and then one digit or it can vary?

Comment: @SouravGhosh sorry but what do you mean by input pattern? how I stored PT3 into the struct? i got the string from a text file of strings, used `strtok` to separate them into specific strings and `strcpy` "PT3" into `c.ID`. the other patient IDs in the file follow the format of PT1, PT2, PT3 ..... PT10 and so on.

Comment: So, instead of `atoi()`, you can use `sscanf(a, "PT%d", &IDno);` and do the error check.

Comment: Don;t edit the question to add the answer. Post an answer which worked for you, and you can even accept your own answer,.

Comment: try `atoi( a + 2 );` to skip the first chars

Comment: @AndersK Better not to recommend solution involving `atoi()` altogether. Alternative `strtol()` is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your problem description, looks like you need [`sscanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf). Something like

```
sscanf(a, "PT%d", &IDno);
```

should do the job. Don't forget to do the error check.